# Using kneighbors() with Knn

Tags: python, jupyter, knn, nearest-neighbor

Problem here:
I am using a knn via a pipeline:

```
knn_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('knn', KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10))
])

knn_pipe.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
```

And I want to use this one with that fit to use NearestNeighbors

Problem: this neirestneighbors needs to be compiled via a fit but I am unable to use the one above, don't know how to extract it from the pipeline.

Any idea?

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the error that appears?

Comment: I try to use this code: from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
                                neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10)
                                neigh.fit(X_tr)  
                                NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10) and can't use this without fitting, precisely I would simply use the fit from above. Otherwise it says the model isn't fitted...

Comment: Error appearing is:

Comment: Error is: this nearestneighbors is not fitted yet.